# Stop activity from finish in TabActivity

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I have used TabActivity i have five tab, in every activity there is database connection 
i want that if i move one tab to another tab the activity should not be finish, so if i come back so activities onCreate() method should not call again

my code is following

```
       public class TabSample extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_main);
    setTabs();

}

private void setTabs() {
    addTab("", R.drawable.a, A.class);
    addTab("", R.drawable.b, B.class);
    addTab("", R.drawable.c, C.class);
    addTab("", R.drawable.d, D.class);
    addTab("", R.drawable.e, E.class);
}



private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c) {
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(labelId);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should your proccess running in **Background Thread (Async Task)** or **Service**. Only result views in Tab activity. İf tab activity is start, you should fill data with Background Thread..